# Was the Dinobots combiner Volcanicus ever animated?

Tags: transformers

Browsing around internet I came across with a Dinobots combiner toy called Volcanicus and an image from it in a comic. Also with this image which some apparently claim comes from a cartoon? [Dinobot combiner](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHkLdPD52HQeqRG0xAAULLGt6gpoza_4wemA&usqp=CAU)

But I couldnt find anything more about it.

Was the Dinobots combiner Volcanicus ever animated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image comes from Season 1, Episode 2 of *[Transformers: Power of the Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Power_of_the_Primes)*.

The episode is available to watch on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ5U9tx9A40).

The image is taken from the 7:23 mark in the video.

Comment: so, it's official but not canon?

Comment: @Pablo I'm not sure what "official but not canon" would mean for _any_ franchise, but for a franchise as diverse as Transformers, there is definitely no single canon you can measure against.

Comment: @IMSoP not part of the main continuity. Many times the main continuity has the creator involved and alternative ones dont

Comment: @Pablo Yeah, I guess that does make sense in some franchises; in this case, though, there is no "main" continuity, because ultimately the creator is a toy company who will licence anything that sells more toys.

Answer (score 1):

The unofficial and irreverent but very detailed TFWiki has information on [a couple of different versions of Volcanicus](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Volcanicus_(disambiguation))

Most notably [the version from the 2017 ''Power of the Primes'' cartoon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Volcanicus_(POTP)) includes [the exact screen grab you link to in the question](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/File:Machinima-POTP-Volcanicus-punches-Windblade.jpg). It mentions several appearances in that TV series, and a tie-in toy, followed by a more recent toy featuring its own background comics.

The [page for a version from the more recent "Cyberverse" cartoon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Volcanicus_(Cyberverse)) is less complete, describing the toy (which oddly isn't actually a combiner), but mentioning two episodes where the character appears.

As far as I can see, both characters are canonical within their own continuities ([identifying any sort of canon across Transformers franchises is ... complicated](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Canon)).